# bash find filenames with the same last four character

Tags: bash, find

I'd like to write a script that will execute a command that finds every set of files that have the same last four characters.

So for example, given a directory with these files,

```
$ ls -1
GH010119.MP4
GH010120.MP4
GH010126.MP4
GH010127.MP4
GH020119.MP4
GH020126.MP4
GH020127.MP4
GH030119.MP4
GH030126.MP4
```

I'd like my script to make out these groups:

```
GH010119.MP4
GH020119.MP4
GH030119.MP4

GH010126.MP4
GH020126.MP4
GH030126.MP4

GH010127.MP4
GH020127.MP4

GH010120.MP4
```

My current solution is to make out each group manually using: `find . -name "*0119*"`, so I'd also like to know if the script I'd have to come up with won't be overly complex in comparison....

Comment: Unless you have a nested directory structure, why use `find`?  `echo *0119.MP4` should do it  or `for fname in *0119.MP4` loop, depending on what you want to do.  If you put that into a function you can call it for different filename patterns.

Comment: *apply some commands to them* - what commands exactly?

Comment: @cdarke: I've clarified my question. Specifically, I want to figure out which files share the same last four characters in their filenames, without me telling it.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696742/ffmpeg-find-chapters-of-same-video-recording

Comment: You should delete this question and keep the other one instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the filenames without extension are all 8 characters and contain no newlines:

```
printf "%s\n" * |
 sort -k1.5,1.8n |
 awk '{key = substr($0,5,4)} NR==1{prev=key} prev != key {print ""} {print; prev=key}'
```

If the filename is not strictly 8 chars, then

```
for f in *; do
   root=${f%%.*}
   echo "${root: -4:4} $f"
done |
 sort -k1,1n |
 awk 'NR==1 {prev=$1} $1 != prev {print ""} {print $2; prev=$1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

With perl

```
perl -e 'for (glob("*")){$f{$1}.="$&\n" if /.*(.{4}).MP4/}print "$_\n" for (values %f)'
GH010126.MP4
GH020126.MP4
GH030126.MP4

GH010120.MP4

GH010119.MP4
GH020119.MP4
GH030119.MP4

GH010127.MP4
GH020127.MP4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the groupings with something like

```
printf '%s\n' *.MP4 | sed 's/.*\(........\)$/\1/' | sort -u
```

With the extension `.MP4` factored in, which is part of the file name no matter how you look at it, this extracts the last eight characters, and removes any duplicates.

Doing it in Awk might be a bit more efficient.

```
awk 'FNR == 1 { n = substr(FILENAME, length(FILENAME)-7);
    if (seen[n]++ == 0) print n; nextfile }' *.MP4
```

Comment: Can use `.\{8\}` instead of all the dots. Don't know if it saves that many chars but I think it's clearer

Comment: Yeah, if your `sed` dialect supports that. Some don't so I wanted to avoid bumping into any portability issues.

Comment: All should support it, it's BRE.

Comment: No blame has been assumed or cast, just asking in the hopes that the drive-by downvoter will explain if something in particular could be fixed here. I personally liked my `printf` solution but it would have been even neater if you could limit the field width from the end with a suitable width specifier, but of course, you can't do that.

Comment: Oh I got a notification so I thought it was addressed to me, since someone thought it was a good idea to remove the `@user` on messages to that user.

Comment: So I gathered. (-: